# BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method - laravel php

Tags: php, laravel

I get the below error when i run my application.In my model, there is a function called `texts()` but still i'm getting the below error. What is the cause of this problem?
When i remove the Foreach loop below

```
`@foreach ($data->fill_texts as $t)
  <div>{{$t->text}} ({{$answer->text_count}})</div>
@endforeach`
```

It works fine with out any error.

> > BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::texts()

**Template Model**

```
  public function texts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Text::class);
  }

  public function fill_texts() 
  {    
    return $this->select('text', DB::raw('count(*) as text_count'))->texts()->groupBy('text')->get();  
  }
```

**Text Model**

```
 protected $table = 'text';


    public function template() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Template::class);
    }
```

**View**

```
  @forelse ($doc->templates as $data)
  @foreach ($data->fill_texts as $t)
      <div>{{$t->text}} ({{$answer->text_count}})</div>
    @endforeach
    @endforelse
```

Comment: You can't use `texts` in that context. You can try `->with('texts')` instead of `->texts()`

Comment: @aynber, i get `unknown column text`. That column is actually in the `text table`. i thought the query `->texts()` will make it possible for me to retrieve that column

Comment: No. `texts()` will return the relationship, so it would be a property of the `$data` object.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. but then why am i getting the error `unknown column text`?

Comment: Is that column in the templates table or the texts table? The select that you're using would get the data from the templates table, and the texts table relationship would be a separate query.

Comment: @aynber, that column is in the texts table.

Comment: Try this inside your fill_texts function: `return $this->hasMany(Text::class)->select('text', DB::raw('count(*) as text_count'))->groupBy('text');`

Comment: @aynber, thanks that worked fine